# How to invert these matrix via Gauss method?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, inverse

Im trying to find the inverse matrix based on
$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 2 & -1\\
0 & 4 & -1\\
-1 & -2 & 1
\end{array}\right]$

$R_{1}=$ First row

$R_{2}=$ Second row

$R_{3}=$Third row

but at a certain step I can't reduce it further. Which must be the next operation?

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 2 & -1\\
0 & 4 & -1\\
-1 & -2 & 1
\end{array}\mid\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$ $\rightarrow\frac{R_{1}}{2}$

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & \frac{-1}{2}\\
0 & 4 & -1\\
-1 & -2 & 1
\end{array}\mid\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$ $\rightarrow R_{3}+R_{1}$

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & \frac{-1}{2}\\
0 & 4 & -1\\
0 & -1 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\mid\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$$\rightarrow\frac{R_{2}}{4}$

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & \frac{-1}{2}\\
0 & 1 & \frac{-1}{4}\\
0 & -1 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\mid\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0\\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$$\rightarrow R_{1}-R_{2}$

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & \frac{-1}{4}\\
0 & 1 & \frac{-1}{4}\\
0 & -1 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\mid\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{4} & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0\\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$$\rightarrow R_{3}+R_{2}$

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & \frac{-1}{4}\\
0 & 1 & \frac{-1}{4}\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4}
\end{array}\mid\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{4} & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} & 1
\end{array}\right]$$\rightarrow4R_{3}$

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & \frac{-1}{4}\\
0 & 1 & \frac{-1}{4}\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\mid\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{4} & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0\\
2 & 1 & 4
\end{array}\right]$$\rightarrow?$

Comment: Now you want to add a multiple of row 3 to both row 1 and row 2 to get rid of the $-1/4$'s. Also, your $R_1-R_2$ step can be delayed until after all the elements below the diagonal have been zeroed out.

Comment: Im going to take your considerations!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing with $R_{1}\rightarrow R_{1}+\frac{1}{4}R_3$ and $R_{2}\rightarrow R_{2}+\frac{1}{4}R_{3}$ we have

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\mid\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 1\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 1\\
2 & 1 & 4
\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: Thanks for the help, I dont know why I didnt see before.

Comment: You're very welcome! :-)